# image disappears when I change css clip: rect property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using clip:rect to clip images into thumbnails and I want to randomise the placing of the clip rectangle on rollover. my code:

```
    $('.itembox').mouseover(function() {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    var width = img[0].width;
    var height = img[0].height;
    var clipwidth = Math.floor( $(this).width() );
    var clipheight = Math.floor( $(this).height() );

    var widthrange = width - clipwidth;
    var heightrange = height - clipheight;

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * widthrange);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * heightrange);
    var x2 = x + clipwidth;
    var y2 = y + clipheight;

    img.css('clip', 'rect('+x+'px '+x2+'px '+y+'px '+y2+'px)');
    $(this).children('.itemboxbg').show();
    $(this).css({'color' : 'white'});

});
```

It works fine with the preset css:

```
.itemboxbg {
    border: none;
    position:absolute;
    width:193px;
    height:273px;
    z-index:0;
}
.itemboxbg img {
    border: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    clip: rect(0px 193px 273px 0px); 
}
```

but when the rollover event fires and it changes the css the image disappears. the css is fine e.g :

```
<img src="./img/exampleimage.png" style="clip: rect(304px 498px 72px 344px);">
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where does .itemboxbg come into play? Is it a wrapper div around the img tag?

Comment: Is it possible that `$('.itembox')` in your JQuery is intended to be `$('.itemboxbg')`?

Comment: nah itembox is the div that holds each item in a grid, the jquery runs fine and updates the css fine, and chrome dev tools shows the element stlye and it looks good, but the image disappears.

Answer (score 0):

silly, it should have been:

```
img.css('clip', 'rect('+y+'px '+x2+'px '+y2+'px '+x+'px)');
```

since clip: rect is defined

```
rect(<top> <right> <bottom> <left>);
```

where `<top>` and `<bottom>` specify offsets from the top border edge of the box, and `<right>` and `<left>` specify offsets from the left border edge of the box.

not a solution yet though, since the image doesn't appear within the box, perhaps I should use background position instead

edit: ok changing the absolute left & top positions moved the image back into the box:

```
img.css('left', -x+'px');
img.css('top', -y+'px');
```